# Nightmare, PhantomJS and extracting page data

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, nightmare

I'm new to Nightmare/PhantomJS and am struggling to get a simple inventory of all the tags on a given page. I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 after building PhantomJS from source and installing NodeJS, Nightmare and so forth manually, and other functions seem to be working as I expect.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
new Nightmare()
  .goto("http://www.google.com")
  .wait()
  .evaluate(function () 
   {
     var a = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
     return(a);
   }, 
   function(i) 
   {
     for (var index = 0; index < i.length; index++)
     if (i[index])
        console.log("Element " + index + ": " + i[index].nodeName);
    })
  .run(function(err, nightmare) 
  {
     if (err) 
        console.log(err);
  });
```

When I run this inside a "real" browser, I get a list of all the tag types on the page (HTML, HEAD, BODY, ...). When I run this using **node GetTags.js**, I just get a single line of output:

```
Element 0: HTML
```

I'm sure it's a newbie problem, but what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhantomJS has two contexts. The page context which provides access to the DOM can only be accessed through `evaluate()`. So, variables must be explicitly passed in and out of the page context. But there is a limitation ([docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

Nightmare's `evaluate()` function is only a wrapper around the PhantomJS function of the same name. This means that you will need to work with the elements in the page context and only pass a *representation* to the outside. For example:

```
.evaluate(function () 
{
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    return a.length;
}, 
function(i) 
{
    console.log(i + " divs available");
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much...really clears things up for me. I changed my code to essentially build a JSON string of the information I want in the part you describe as the "page context", and then return it to the script. I suppose the part that threw me was that I was getting a single line of output rather than an error of some sort...anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Is this still working ? For some reason that doesn't work for me.. Unable to console.log() like that.

Comment: @RetroCode I haven't tried, but I've looked into the code for v2 and it still looks like it should work this way. Remember that Nightmare v2 was basically a full rewrite with promises and Electron instead of PhantomJS.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Does nightmare v2 still has the restriction "The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine"?

Comment: @OgrishMan Sorry, I haven't tried it and I'm not familiar with how Electron handles this. This was essentially a restriction of PhantomJS and not of Nightmare.